# Is it possible to linearize $y = axe^{bx}$ in a linear regression?

Tags: statistics, regression

Is it possible to linearize $y = axe^{bx}$ in a linear regression?

My try: $y = axe^{bx} \to ln(y/x) = ln(a)+bx$.

Can I do $Y = ln(y/x)$. $A =ln(a)$ and $B = b$?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn´t look like that the equation can be linearized. You have $x$ and $y$ on one side. This is not valid. $x$ and $y$ have to be on different sides of the equation. Are you sure that $y=a\cdot e^{bx}$ is not meant ? $x$ (variable) and $\times$ (multiplication sign) can be mixed up very easily.

Comment: Thanks @caliculus. Must be an error of the teacher.

Comment: Are you able to manage it with the "new" equation ?

Comment: Yes, I can do this exercise now, Thanks for the help.

Comment: That´s nice. Your are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It could be some misunderstanding somewhere (probably a wording problem).

Let us suppose that you have data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to fit the model $$y = axe^{bx}$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(y)=\log(a)+\log(x)+b x=\alpha+\log(x)+b x$$ So, the residue is $$r_i=\alpha+\log(x_i)+b x_i-\log(y_i)=\alpha+b x_i-\log(\frac{y_i}{x_i})$$ which is the same as for model $$z=a e^{bx}\implies \log(z)=\alpha+b x$$ (using $z=\frac y x$).

So, the original model can be linearized. A simple linear regression will give $\alpha$ (then $a=e^\alpha$) and $b$. But, for sure, this is just the preliminary step before a nonlinear regression since what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(y)$ and still less $\log(\frac y x)$.